# Pyspark: Create a spark dataframe from RDD of lists where some elements of list are objects

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to convert a pandas.DataFrame code to equivalent pyspark DataFrame.
I have an RDD of the below format.

```
myRdd = [[1, 'a', {'a':[1, 2]}],
         [2, 'b', {'c': 1, 'd':3}],
         [3, 'c', {}]]

columnNames = ['sl', 'name', 'params']
```

The third element in the inner list does not have a specific structure.
In pandas dataframe, I can treat the third column as dtype=object.

```
pdDF = pandas.DataFrame(myRdd, columns=columnNames)
```

Can I do something similar to convert the a pyspark RDD of above format to pyspark DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `dtype=object` in Spark, but you could define a custom schema to convert your `rdd` into a DataFrame and have the `params` column be a `StructType()`. You can not use `MapType()` because the values have to be the same type for all keys.

For example:

```python
myRdd = [[1, 'a', {'a':[1, 2]}],
         [2, 'b', {'c': 1, 'd':3}],
         [3, 'c', {}]]

schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField('sl', IntegerType()),
        StructField('name', StringType()),
        StructField(
            'params',
            StructType(
                [
                    StructField('a', ArrayType(IntegerType())),
                    StructField('c', IntegerType()),
                    StructField('d', IntegerType())
                ]
            )
        )
    ]
)

rdd = sc.parallelize(myRdd)
df = rdd.toDF(schema)
df.show()
#+---+----+------------------------------+
#|sl |name|params                        |
#+---+----+------------------------------+
#|1  |a   |[WrappedArray(1, 2),null,null]|
#|2  |b   |[null,1,3]                    |
#|3  |c   |[null,null,null]              |
#+---+----+------------------------------+
```

Then to access a particular element, you can use the `getItem()` method or use `"."` in a select. For example, to pull the value of the key `"a"` for each row, you could do either of the following:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.select("sl", "name", f.col("params").getItem("a")).show()
#+---+----+--------+
#| sl|name|params.a|
#+---+----+--------+
#|  1|   a|  [1, 2]|
#|  2|   b|    null|
#|  3|   c|    null|
#+---+----+--------+

df.select("sl", "name", "params.a").show()
#+---+----+------+
#| sl|name|     a|
#+---+----+------+
#|  1|   a|[1, 2]|
#|  2|   b|  null|
#|  3|   c|  null|
#+---+----+------+
```

Or you can use `".*"` to access all of the elements as separate columns:

```python
df.select("sl", "name", "params.*").show()
#+---+----+------+----+----+
#| sl|name|     a|   c|   d|
#+---+----+------+----+----+
#|  1|   a|[1, 2]|null|null|
#|  2|   b|  null|   1|   3|
#|  3|   c|  null|null|null|
#+---+----+------+----+----+
```

The schema of the DataFrame is:

```python
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- sl: integer (nullable = true)
# |-- name: string (nullable = true)
# |-- params: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |-- a: array (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
# |    |-- c: integer (nullable = true)
# |    |-- d: integer (nullable = true)
```

As this implies, the datatype for a specific member of the struct must be the same throughout- this means, for example, that `params.a` must be a list of ints for every row.